Degenerate spectrum for the sum of projections onto unit vectors that sum to zero implies a symmetry of the vectors?
I am interested in a sum of projections $A = \sum_{i=1}^N \mathbf{a}_i\,\mathbf{a}_i^T$, where $\mathbf{a}_i$ are real column vectors with unit norm and $\sum_i \mathbf{a}_i = \mathbf{0}$.
So $A$ is a real positive matrix with an eigenvector decomposition $A = \sum_{j=1}^d \lambda_j \mathbf{e}_j\,\mathbf{e}_j^T$, where $\lambda_j\ge 0$, $d$ is the dimension of $A$, $\mathbf{e}_j$ are unit vectors, $\sum_j \mathbf{e}_j\,\mathbf{e}_j^T = \mathbb{I}$.
Does degenerate spectrum of the sum of projections $A$ imply a symmetry of the multiset of unit vectors $\{\mathbf{a}_i\}$?

''Degenerate spectrum'' here means a spectrum with a single distinct eigenvalue and all the other eigenvalues are the same;

''Symmetry'' here means that the multiset of unit vectors can be divided into $\cup_j \mathcal{S}_j$, where each set of vectors $\mathcal{S}_j$ is generated by applying matrix representations $\{Q^k |k\in\mathbf{Z}\}$ of some cyclic group over real vector space onto some unit vector $u$: $\mathcal{S}_j = \{Q^k u|k\in\mathbf{Z}\}$.


My struggle with this question:
When $d = 3$, consider a multiset of unit vectors $\mathcal{S} = \{\mathbf{a}_{i}\}$, decompose each unit vector $\mathbf{a}_{i}$ into $\mathbf{a}_{i,\perp}$ and $\mathbf{a}_{i,\parallel}$, the perpendicular and parallel components with respect to a unit vector $\mathbf{e}_k$.
If the unit vectors in $\mathcal{S}$ have rotational symmetry around axis $\mathbf{e}_k$, then the sum of projections $A$ has an eigenvector $\mathbf{e}_k$.
More generally, if we have a union of rotational symmetric sets, $\mathcal{S} = \mathcal{S}_1 \cup \mathcal{S}_2\cup\dots\cup \mathcal{S}_M$, then the sum of projections $A$ for $\mathcal{S}$ also has an eigenvector $\mathbf{e}_k$.
My question now is in two parts:

In $d=3$, suppose the sum of projections $A$ for a multiset of unit vectors $\{\mathbf{a}_{i}\}$ that sum to zero satisfies
\begin{equation}
A =  \sum_{\mathbf{a}_{i}\in \mathcal{S}} \mathbf{a}_{i}\mathbf{a}_{i}^T = \lambda_\perp \mathbb{I}_\perp + \lambda_\parallel \mathbf{e}_k \mathbf{e}_k^T \,,\tag{1}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbb{I}_\perp$ is the projection onto the subspace perpendicular to $\mathbf{e}_k$, $\lambda_\parallel\neq\lambda_\perp$.
Is it necessary that the multiset $\mathcal{S} = \{\mathbf{a}_{i}\}$ has the structure of a union of rotational symmetric sets $\mathcal{S} = \mathcal{S}_1 \cup \mathcal{S}_2\cup\dots\cup \mathcal{S}_M$?

What statement can we make when $d> 3$?



This question is linked to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506883/sum-of-projections-onto-vectors-which-sum-to-zero
